# How to efficiently read large excel file from angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xlsx, filereader

I am trying to open large file from angular application and it is working fine. But for large file it is taking too much time and sometime browser crashing quite frequently. Please help me to read the file properly without crashing the browsers and load very fast.
Here is the stack blitz link https://angular-atyjhm.stackblitz.io
Specially around 1 GB file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly, use Angular [web-workers](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker) to read the file in a separate thread so your browser won't freeze and crash
2. Read the file in chunks using [sheetJs](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) and send data as a message to the main thread.

```
const worker = new Worker(new URL('./app.worker', import.meta.url));
worker.postMessage(excelData);
```

3. Listen for the message from the webworker and update the UI in asynchronously.